# How to compile VLC 3.0.3 tarball on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, vlc

I'm trying to [report a VLC crash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465673/3645), but compilation fails:

```
$ ./configure CFLAGS="-g" CXXFLAGS="-g" --enable-debug && make
[…]
  CC       codec/libx264_plugin_la-x264.lo
In file included from ../include/vlc_fixups.h:31,
                 from ../config.h:907,
                 from codec/x264.c:29:
/usr/include/features.h:381:4: warning: #warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O) [-Wcpp]
 #  warning _FORTIFY_SOURCE requires compiling with optimization (-O)
    ^~~~~~~
codec/x264.c: In function ‘Open’:
codec/x264.c:849:26: error: ‘x264_bit_depth’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘x264_picture_t’?
         const int mask = x264_bit_depth > 8 ? X264_CSP_HIGH_DEPTH : 0;
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          x264_picture_t
codec/x264.c:849:26: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

There doesn't seem to be an x264 library package:

```
$ pacman --sync --search x264
extra/x264 2:155.r0a84d986-2 [installed]
    Open Source H264/AVC video encoder
```

How do I get past this step? I've already installed all the build dependencies of the [vlc-git AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vlc-git/).

Comment: may check if `ffmpeg0.10` is installed, i have seen this package causing problems (with similar errors like yours) in different build processes on my machine.

Comment: Does it build using the official PKGBUILD? Notably the same flags?

Comment: @jasonwryan vlc-git at least compiles using PKGBUILD

Comment: Building the official  3.0.3.r1-2 works fine for me.

Comment: @jasonwryan Did you use the same commands I did? Also, can you tell where the definition of `x264_bit_depth` came from during compilation?

Comment: No, I built it using the PKGBUILD. Just add the debug flags that you want and `makepkg`.

Comment: I need to build the version I'm running. I was able to find the 3.0.3 [PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System#Retrieve_PKGBUILD_source_using_Svn). The tarball GPG verification failed because the key expired in June, but that's probably not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @jasonwryan's comments I was able to modify the official VLC 3.0.3 [PKGBUILD](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System#Retrieve_PKGBUILD_source_using_Svn) to build a debug version of VLC. The PKGBUILD diff:

```
$ diff PKGBUILD{.orig,}
125c125
<   export CFLAGS+=" -I/usr/include/samba-4.0"
---
>   export CFLAGS+=" -I/usr/include/samba-4.0 -g"
127c127
<   export CXXFLAGS+=" -std=c++11"
---
>   export CXXFLAGS+=" -std=c++11 -g"
222c222,223
<               --with-kde-solid=/usr/share/solid/actions/
---
>               --with-kde-solid=/usr/share/solid/actions/ \
>               --enable-debug
```

Unfortunately this was not enough to provide enough information to the developers.